# jQuery: "href" from dynamic <a> then apply href to neighbor element? both in same div

Tags: javascript, jquery

So i'm using RSS elements that show dynamic content, obviously. The URL/href is always different, so i'm looking to duplicate the entire href of the  element, and apply the href property to an element underneath it that doesn't actually have a href attribute. I've been messing around with many iterations and examples, but I just can't seem figure it out.

Broken code:

```
$().ready(function(){
  $('.mm').attr('href',$('.mm a').closest('.test1').attr('href'))
})
```

Current HTML markup example:

```
<div class="rssFeed">

  <h3>        
    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/top/.rss?sort=top&amp;t=week&amp;limit=5" target="_blank">
      sustainability</a>      
  </h3>

  <div class="mm">

    <span class="rssFeedTitle j-rss-feed-title">
      Trees that helped save America's farms
    </span><br><br>

    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vqzku/trees_that_helped_save_americas_farms_during_the/" target="_blank">
      &gt;&gt; Read More
    </a><br><br>

    <div class="tw" href="http://sharewithtwitter.com/share=">
      Twitter
    </div>

    <div class="fb" href="http://sharewithfacebook.com/share=">
      Facebook
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="wrappedtext">(Tue, 06 Feb 2018)</div>

  <div class="mm">

    <span class="rssFeedTitle j-rss-feed-title">
      Can Money Grow on Trees? Across the world, businesses are 
      making money by restoring forests and farmland.</span><br><br>

    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vx4qu/can_money_grow_on_trees_across_the_world/" target="_blank">
      &gt;&gt; Read More
    </a><br><br>

    <div class="tw" href="http://sharewithtwitter.com/share=">
      Twitter
    </div>

    <div class="fb" href="http://sharewithfacebook.com/share=">
      Facebook
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="wrappedtext">(Wed, 07 Feb 2018)</div>

</div>
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
<div class="rssFeed">

  <h3>

    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/top/.rss?sort=top&amp;t=week&amp;limit=5" target="_blank">
      sustainability
    </a>

  </h3>

  <div class="mm">

    <span class="rssFeedTitle j-rss-feed-title">
      Trees that helped save America's farms
    </span><br><br>

    <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vqzku/trees_that_helped_save_americas_farms_during_the/" target="_blank">
      &gt;&gt; Read More</a><br><br>

    <div class="tw" href="http://sharewithtwitter.com/share=https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vqzku/trees_that_helped_save_americas_farms_during_the/">
      Twitter
    </div>

    <div class="fb" href="http://sharewithfacebook.com/share=https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vqzku/trees_that_helped_save_americas_farms_during_the/">
      Facebook
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="wrappedtext">(Tue, 06 Feb 2018)</div>

  <div class="mm">

    <span class="rssFeedTitle j-rss-feed-title">
      Can Money Grow on Trees? Across the world, businesses are 
      making money by restoring forests and farmland.</span><br><br>

      <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vx4qu/can_money_grow_on_trees_across_the_world/" target="_blank">
        &gt;&gt; Read More</a><br><br>

      <div class="tw" href="http://sharewithtwitter.com/share=https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vx4qu/can_money_grow_on_trees_across_the_world/">
        Twitter
      </div>

      <div class="fb" href="http://sharewithfacebook.com/share=https://www.reddit.com/r/sustainability/comments/7vx4qu/can_money_grow_on_trees_across_the_world/">
        Facebook
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="wrappedtext">(Wed, 07 Feb 2018)</div>

</div>
```

The detailed idea, is getting a href value from a topic/story link, and adding it to share button. Based on other code, the href value will be changed in the beginning of the url so it can be shared on social media as such:

```
$(".fb").attr("href", function(i, href) {
  return 'http://sharewithfacebook.com/share=' + href;
});
```

Im trying to avoid implementing the code social media sites provide for privacy reasons for my users.

codepin: https://codepen.io/zachreynolds/pen/oEBMzz

Comment: found something that might work http://jsfiddle.net/tuAUb/

Comment: I some what figured it out, https://codepen.io/zachreynolds/pen/oEBMzz, i added one for facebook and one for twitter, the problem is it is showing 3 "share" buttons instead of 2, don't know why its showing 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HALF WORKING**, i put a box for twitter and facebook, they are linked, how ever, its adding 3 boxes and multiplies all each time? I have no idea why.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mm').each(function () {
        $('a', this).after('<a class="tw">twitter</a><br>');
        var lnk = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $('a.tw', this).attr('href', lnk);
    });
});


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.mm').each(function () {
        $('a', this).after('<a class="fb">facebook</a><br>');
        var lnk = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $('a.fb', this).attr('href', lnk);
    });
});
```

codepin is updated

https://codepen.io/zachreynolds/pen/oEBMzz